# permission denied as root

Tags: permissions, sudo, su

I am trying to run chown on a directory and I get a permission denied.
I have tried running sudo and also running the command as root.

If root doesn't have permission, how can I change the owner of this directory?

thanks

Comment: What filesystem type is the drive that the directory is on?

Comment: Is the directory `.gvfs`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying this on a read-only filesystem. (mounted with option ro, or some other way) If that is the case, there is no way you can achieve what you are trying other than changing the read/write status of the filesystem in question.

With more details we can help you more:
at a minimum, look at the full path name and see how your filesystems are mounted
(output of `mount`). You can post both in your question by editing it and we might be able to help you more.

Edit: How to find that your mount options by using commandline mount:

```
DrSAR@localhost ~ mount

/dev/sdc2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6673.snap on /snap/core/6673 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

The details are not important except for the first option in brackets which states `rw` for read-write filesystems (like your main hard disk mounted at root /) or `ro` in the second case.

Comment: can you give some details on what we should look for in the output of `mount`? Like how can we know if we are in a read only filesystem?